# Появляется сразу три яндекс.карты через API. Как исправить?

Tags: javascript, api

Я написал следующий код. Я брал массив с адресом и названием товара. С помощью geocode() я получал геоданные
и выкладывал их на карту, но у меня вместо одной карты выходит 3.
Я конечно понял, что это происходит из за того, что функция вызывается три раза в foreach.Как можно это поправить-подскажите,пожалуйста.

```js
const arr = [{
    "address": "Ярославское шоссе, 8к1",
    "product": "васса3"
  },
  {
    "address": "Большая Очаковская",
    "product": "васса2"
  },
  {
    "address": "Большая Очаковская",
    "product": "васса2"
  }
];


arr.forEach((item) => {
  const geocode = 'Россия, Москва,' + item.address + "'";
  const product = item.product;
  getTest(geocode, product);
});

const acc = [];
async function getTest(geocode, product) {

  const response = await fetch("https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?format=json&apikey=c89368db-e7f4-4942-835a-1c7df2f555ce&geocode=geocode" + geocode + '"', {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Accept": "application/json"
    }
  });

  const points = await response.json();
  array = points.response.GeoObjectCollection.featureMember;

  array.forEach(item => {
    const pos = item.GeoObject.Point.pos;

    const posString = pos;
    const splitsPosition = posString.split(' ', 3);

    function swap(arr, a, b) {
      arr[a] = arr.splice(b, 1, arr[a])[0];
    }
    console.log(swap(splitsPosition, 0, 1));

    acc.unshift({
      ['address']: splitsPosition,
      ['product']: product
    });


  });


  ymaps.ready(init);

  function init() {
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
      center: [55.852713, 37.682727],
      zoom: 16
    }, {
      searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
    });

    var myCollection = new ymaps.GeoObjectCollection();
    //здесь перебираю координаты
    acc.forEach((element) => {
      var myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(
        element.address,

        {
          balloonContentHeader: 'Товар:',
          balloonContent: element.product
        }, {
          preset: 'islands#icon',
          iconColor: '#0000ff'
        });
      myCollection.add(myPlacemark);


    });



    myMap.geoObjects.add(myCollection);


    myMap.setBounds(myCollection.getBounds(), {
      checkZoomRange: true,
      zoomMargin: 9
    });
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Компании</title>
  <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

</head>

<body>
  <style>
    .form {
      margin-bottom: 300px;
    }
  </style>
  <div class="container">
    <a href="{{url('/users')}}" class="btn btn-success">Сотрудники</a>
    <a href="{{url('/company')}}" class="btn btn-success">Компании</a>
    <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height:500px"></div>
  </div>

  <form class="form" id="form">
    <textarea id="textarea" name="textarea" rows="10" cols="70">
</textarea>
    <button type="submit" id="button">Отправить</button>
  </form>
  <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru-RU" type="text/javascript"></script>



  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: А нельзя сначала взять у api ваши три точки, а затем вызвать Одну карту и уже на ней расставить их? Мне кажется, нужно мыслить в этом направлении. Получать точки, а потом расставлять их на карте. А не три раза карту вызывать.

Comment: @Grekov , Спасибо за комментарий. Я уже так и сделал. Видимо уставший был , поэтому сразу к этому не пришел)